# Integrate Parse.com with Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, web, parse-platform

I am doing a web and I have the data in Parse.com and I need use Codeigniter, but there is a config file in Codeigniter "database.php" that has some parameters like this:

```
['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
['username'] The username used to connect to the database
['password'] The password used to connect to the database
['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
['dbdriver'] The database type.
```

And I don't know how edit this file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library for using parse.com with codeigniter is available for this.

[Codeigniter Parse.com Library](https://github.com/st028/codeigniter-parse.com-library)

Parse.com is an API not direct database access so you will not be able to use the database library to talk to it.